# Аналог функции sha1($data, true) на c#

Tags: c#, sha1

Для взаимодействия с API необходимо применить к запросу шифрование типа sha1($data, true). На просторах интернета есть информация только по стандартному алгоритму, который возвращает 40-символьную строку. Хотелось бы получить совет минимум в каком направлении копать. Возможно импортировать функцию из PHP или ещё что-то в этом роде. P.S. Соре за глупые вопросы.

Comment: может всё же sha256 https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: sha1($data, true) в документации написано вот так. Проверял на PHP - строка из 20 символов, а SHA256 возвращает строку размером 64 символа. ._.

Comment: я к тому, что может 256 использовать? ибо sha1 уже старовата, также как и md5....... или api тоже не ваше, а стороннее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот аналог функции sha1 из PHP, если передашь false то строка будет равна 40 символов, если true то 20.

```
private static string Sha1(string data, bool rawOutput = false)
{
    var hash = new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

    return rawOutput
            ? Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hash)
            : string.Join("", hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")).ToArray());
}


static void Main()
{
    var sha1 = Sha1("Мама", true);

    Console.WriteLine(sha1);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё работает.